# How do I perform bitwise logic within JSTL if statements?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a need to perform a bitwise test within a JSP but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it with EL.

I want to do something like:

```
<c:if test="${(test & testFor) == testFor}">
  <h3>Test Passed</h3>
</c:if>
```

Of course I can do it with ordinary JSP syntax:

```
<% if ((test & testFor) == testFor) { %>
  <h3>Test Passed</h3>
<% } %>
```

Comment: An EL function is indeed the way to go. You can find examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472699/jstl-fmt-library-throws-500-error-requires-sessions-enabled/3472823#3472823), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752949/jsp-2-0-seo-friendly-links-encoding/2753495#2753495) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet/2525995#2525995).

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help BalusC, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think bitwise operators are not implemented in JSTL ([see here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=4))

You can implement a JSTL function, called `bitwiseAnd(int, int)` and perform the bitwise test in Java code

Comment: Thanks heaps, much appreciative.

Answer (score 3):

JSP EL doesn't support bitwise operators (only arithmetic, logical and relational operators). If you want to do that, you'll need to encapsulate the operations within a java class, and expose that to the JSP. Alternatively, I believe you can write a custom function, that would look similar to those in the `fn:` JSTL namespace, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Thanks heaps, much appreciative, both your and Bozho's answers were very similar, but I had to choose one :)