# How to translate "Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet" into SEO friendly "Lorem-3-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet" in Java?

Tags: java, regex, seo, friendly-url

In my blog app, a user can enter any text as a title for their entry and then I generate a URL based on the text.

I validate their title to make sure **it only contains letters and numbers**.

If they enter something like

```
Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet
```

how could I generate the more SEO friendly version of this text:

```
Lorem-3-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet
```

Comment: The `[slug]` tag seems to be related to the question. I started to look for a few links in e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224419/need-a-simple-regular-expression/3224533#3224533

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in practice really not as simple as replacing spaces by hypens. You would often also like to make it all lowercase and normalize/replace diacritics, like á, ö, è and so on which are **invalid** URL characters. The only valid characters are listed as "Unreserved characters" in the 2nd table of [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Here's how such a function can look like:

```
public static String prettyURL(String string) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(string.toLowerCase(), Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
        .replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", "-");
}
```

It does basically the following:

- lowercase the string
- remove combining [diacritical marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) (after the Normalizer has "extracted" them from the actual chars)
- replace non-alphanumeric characters by hyphens

#### See also:

- [JSP 2.0 SEO friendly links encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752949/jsp-2-0-seo-friendly-links-encoding)

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet"
s = s.replaceAll(" ","-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it won't seem to allow me to comment.  I would do:

```
String s = "Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet"
s = s.replaceAll(" ","_");
```

Using the Underscore character instead because it is a space indicator.  Its been a while since I've done java but I know there is a function in .Net that will cleanup a file name so its safe for the file system.  I lot of the same general rules applies to a URL so if you can find one in the API it be worth taking a look.