# Regex for replacing à,Á,Ä etc. -> a, Õ,ò, etc. -> o

Tags: .net, regex, unicode

Western Latin character set contains characters such as 
À Á Â Ã Ä Å which have all the same standard char 'a' as 'radix'. This happens on e,i,o,etc. as well.
Is there a regex for replacing these variations to their 'radix' characters?

This would be used to create a seo friendly url from a text (but not limited to):

Example: La cena è pronta => La cena e pronta

Comment: Regexes are probably not the best tool to use for that. It would be easier to normalize to NFKD and then removing all non-spacing modifiers from the result. (But actually, what is it you want to _achieve_?)

Comment: @Daniel A. White: my question is pretty clear in its scope! I do not see what there is not clear.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: thanks, i do not know about NFKD, now i will check.

Comment: please show a more clear example.

Comment: @Valerio The question is *not* clear. You only say what you *think* you need. You do not say what you want to do. You may very well be wrong about what you think you need.

Comment: @Tomalak i do not think to be so stupid to not knowing what i want to do. as stated in question, i want to replace À Á Â Ã Ä Å to a, È 
É Ê Ë to e, etc.

Comment: I think that Henning Makholm has correctly replied to my question. Thanks. If you leave the answer, i will vote for accepted solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: Don't use regex. You ain't ever going to reliably cover all diacritics in a single regex. Use a normalizer. See the possible duplicate link. For interests in Java, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658991/how-to-translate-lorem-3-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-into-seo-friendly-lorem-3-ipsum/3659154#3659154).

Comment: @BalusC Technically you can use Regex for Phase 2 :-) Yeah it's probably overkill, but it's some less lines of code :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string str = "La cena è pronta àèéìòùçæÀÈÉÌÒÙÇÆ";
str = str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD); // Or use NormalizationForm.FormKD
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\p{Mn}", "");
// Result: La cena e pronta aeeioucæAEEIOUCÆ
```

But note that `Æ` remains `Æ`.

Comment: For URL generation, it would probably be better to select specifically, the ASCII letters in the normalized string.

Comment: Why FormD instead of initial suggested FormKD?

Comment: @Valerio True... We are already taking away the marks... We could use the KD. The difference between the two is that `FormD` preservers formatting information, `FormKD` doesn't. But for example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net/249126#249126 they use `FormD`